# can someone please explain to me this code - python 3

Tags: python

why when i put square brackets in line 4 the output change ?

```py
def x(a, b):
    d = []
    for i in range(0, a):
        d += str(i) + b
    return d
c = x(3, "7")
print(c)
```

Output:

```
['0', '7', '1', '7', '2', '7']
```

```py
def x(a, b):
    d = []
    for i in range(0, a):
        d += [str(i) + b]
    return d
c = x(3, "7")
print(c)
```

Output:

```
['07', '17', '27']
```

why the output changed like this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its simple,

```
d += 'a' + 'b' # is same as [] + list('ab') = ['a', 'b']
```

Similarly

```
d += ['a' + 'b'] # is same as [] + ['ab'] = ['ab']
```

When you type convert a string to list, it creates a list of individual character as elements of list.

For Example:

```
a = "Good"
b = list(a)
print(b) # will print as --> ['G', 'o', 'o', 'd']
```